# Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am able to connect to snowflake using browser but while trying with snowpark connection am not able to connect to it. I can connect with the same credential with different laptop but in a specific laptop its not possible is there way to use  insecure_mode=True

```
connection_parameters = {
"account": "YYXXXX.XYZ.XYZ.azure",
"user": "USERNAME",
"password": "PASSWORD",
"warehouse": "WAREHOUSE_NAME", 
"database": "DATABASE_NAME", 
"schema": "PUBLIC" 
 }
session =Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
```

Comment: If you log into the Snowflake browser with that user/password, I assume you can use the warehouse/database/schema? Do you have log files that provide anymore information about the connection attempt? Can you expand your code sample to show how this connection is actually being used?

Comment: sorry to say i dont have any logfile and this is the only syntax to connect to snowflake using snowpark. I'm just trying this code from jupyter notebook. if "Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()" gets successful then am able to access the table from snowflake

Comment: Do you have a proxy in the network? The browser can use a script for proxy while clients like Snowpark can't and need to have manually specified the proxy parameters.

Comment: I've no idea if this is related to your particular issue but when I get connection issues it is often due to the account value. Snowflake seems to have a number of different ways of identifying accounts - some include the Org if you have an Org structure, some include .snowflake.com and some don't - and unless you use exactly the account identifier the connection is expecting then it errors. However I can't help you with whether the account value you are using is correct and, if not, what it should be

Comment: there is a chance of proxy. any ides how to come over of this? or how to specify the proxy parameter. @Sergiu

Comment: @Kyle Snowpark Python uses Snowflake's Python connector for connectivity with Snowflake account, therefore follow [these](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example#using-a-proxy-server) to add the proxy parameters. To confirm the proxy, test with [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd) if you have a chance to install it.